# Simple numerical expression solver

Tags: c++, data-structures, binary-tree

First of all, sorry for my bad English.

For my last project on my Algorithms and Data Structures class, I need to create a simple numerical expression solver in C++. It needs to solve simple expressions like `3*12+(4-6)`. I managed to split the expression and separate the operators from the numbers, but I can't go any further. The trick is putting the operators on a binary tree, but I haven't managed to do that.

The program needs to use only the default C++ libs. Maybe there is some basic implementation I can build on?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Convert from infix to postfix notation using stacks. Then evaluate the postfix expression. http://www.cs.man.ac.uk/~pjj/cs212/fix.html

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Your English seems fine, don't let that trouble you. Your post, however, is missing a key element: a question. StackOverflow is a question-and-answer site. Do you have a a question?

Comment: @Robᵩ penultimate sentence is a question...

Comment: @Astor: "Thanks in advance" is the last sentence :D

Comment: @Robᵩ Thanks! I was just asking for an reference implementation so I can build my code on. I'm still a little confused with this commentimg system, so sorry if I make any mistake.

Comment: @VanDarg Interesting link, maybe an prefix solution would be easier?

Comment: @danielpontello: Yes!(rather postfix) For the conversion, you shouldn't need a stack (but you could use one). `You can convert directly between these bracketed forms simply by moving the operator within the brackets`. And then evaluate the expression with a stack. I did the exact same assignment in my Data Structures class. The bottom line is, there are many ways to go about this.

Comment: See http://faculty.cs.niu.edu/~hutchins/csci241/eval.htm.

Comment: @VanDarg Yeah, seems like this problem accepts multiple solutions. As soon as I get home I'll try doing it. Thanks again!

Comment: @DougRamsey "penultimate" means "next-to-last"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Forget binary trees for a moment.

You need to convert the expression into [reverse polish notation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reverse_Polish_notation). During that conversion you are constructing a binary tree!

[Reverse polish notation][2]

Comment: As VanDarg said above, seems that this is the best solution. Anyway, I'll try postfixing everything and see what I got. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Look at this http://www.codeproject.com/KB/recipes/rwformulaparser.aspx I think this project will solve your problem
Josemi

Answer (score 0):

You will want to convert it into reverse polish notation, the algorithm for the conversion is a little complicated, but many websites detail the exact steps. Doing multi-digit numbers will make it a little more complicated.

The most important thing you need to know is that for RPN, you will have to use a stack, not a binary tree. Once an equation is switched to RPN, you will empty it's numbers into a stack until you run into a operator, where you will then take the top two numbers from the stack and do the operation on them and put that final value back onto the stack. In the end you will be left with one number on the stack and it will be the answer to your equation.